# How create table structure from SQL View?

Tags: sql-server

I need create a table structure from a sql view.

I work with Azure SQL

```
CREATE TABLE ProvidersByNameOrLocation
    AS
    (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(C.name, ' ', Y.name, ' (', Y.max_length, ') ', IIF(C.is_nullable = 1, '', 'NOT '), 'NULL'), ', ')
        FROM SYS.all_columns C
        INNER JOIN SYS.all_objects T
        ON C.object_id = T.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.types Y
        ON C.system_type_id = Y.system_type_id
        WHERE T.name = 'tableName'
    )
```

Comment: Not very sure about azure, but select top 0 * into tablename from ProvidersByNameOrLocation will generally do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not support this Oracle syntax.  So, you will probably have to create the table manually and then populate it using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE ProvidersByNameOrLocation (some_col varchar(200));
INSERT INTO ProvidersByNameOrLocation (some_col)
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(C.name, ' ', Y.name, ' (', Y.max_length, ') ', IIF(C.is_nullable = 1, '', 'NOT '), 'NULL'), ', ')
FROM SYS.all_columns C
INNER JOIN SYS.all_objects T
    ON C.object_id = T.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types Y
    ON C.system_type_id = Y.system_type_id
WHERE T.name = 'tableName';
```